# c9 and heroku / rake aborted! undefined method `mount'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Everything working fine on the development environment(C9). However, when it comes to deploying to Heroku, when I try to run 'heroku rake db:migrate', I get the following error message:

```
breadeat:~/workspace/KNU_Community_Sy_part (master) $ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ arcane-woodland-11170... up, run.6105 (Free)
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `mount' for #<Kcm::Application:0x00000002c99d00>
/app/config/environments/production.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:211:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:211:in `configure'
/app/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:48:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

help plz..

my code in github
link_to : https://github.com/sangyeol-kim/KNU_Community_Sy_part

For reference, I have installed the Heroku redis add-on.

Comment: It's hard to read your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/environments/production.rb` on [line 2](https://github.com/sangyeol-kim/KNU_Community_Sy_part/blob/master/config/environments/production.rb#L2), change this:

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

to this:

```
config.action_cable.mount_path = "/cable"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'` in config/environments/production.rb

https://github.com/sangyeol-kim/KNU_Community_Sy_part/blob/3dc80e210f3a8d40fb9184877098560c65d3b37f/config/environments/production.rb#L2

Remove that and try it out.